# use more that one abstract/common models in other django models

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have a situation like this:

```
class master1(models.Model):
   contacts = ...
   description = ...

class master2(models.Model):
   contacts = ...

class master3(models.Model):
   description = ...
```

I have some attributes and methods that are used in some models. for example `description` is used in `master1` and `master3` but not in `master2`. on the other hands `contacts` are used in `master1, master2`.
So I can't create an `abstract` model and just inherit from them.

I want to have two separate models like this:

```
class DescriptionMixin(models.Model):
    description = ...
    class Meta:
       abstract = true

class ContactsMixin(models.Model):
    contacts = ...
    class Meta:
       abstract = true
```

#### My question is:

Is this OK if I inherit from them like this:

```
class master1(DescriptionMixin, ContactsMixin):
   contacts = ...
   description = ...

class master2(ContactsMixin):
   contacts = ...

class master3(DescriptionMixin):
   description = ...
```

I guess it's not a good way, because in `master1` it inherits from `models.Model` two times.

1- Is it a good approach?

2- any other solution you may suggest?

**Note:** this is just a simple representation of it, but you'll get the idea.

thanks in advance

Comment: It is not a problem to "inherit from models.Model two times". Python deals with multiple inheritance correctly.

Comment: Great thanks. By the way if you had any other solution or usefull links I appreciate it.

Comment: Almost. seem like multiple inheritance of abstract models can be handled properly in python. I wasn't sure at the moment of question. But looking at this blog post, it seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

[Remember to set proper Meta if you want your model to only provide columns and logic without creating table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)
Excerpt from docs: 
`Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common information into a number of other models. You write your base class and put abstract=True in the Meta class.`

Comment: Please read the question more carefully. I updated it for better understanding.

Comment: Your question at the time of writing of this answer suggested the issue was with actual model inheritance and how to achieve it in Django. Now you're simply asking for opinions.

Comment: Sorry if details was not enough. I updated it. Now I will be thankful if you have any suggestions?